# Display Code as Code and Not as executable script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, input

I have created a form maker somewhat like Formtorch for codeigniter.
The form consists of 6 text boxes that when submitted go to a php file for execution via ajax. Everything works except for my display.  This is what I want to display as code and not as executable script. The idea is to simply copy and paste this to quickly make a form.

```
<p>
   <label for="<?php $v1;?>"><?php echo $v1;?></label>       
   <input type="text" name="<?php $v1;?>" id="<?php $v1;?>" />       
   <label class="error" id="<?php $v1;?>">This field is required</label>
</p>
```

As you might expect, when this is returned to the Ajax success script it comes out as labels and input boxes. My ajax display is like this:

```
 success: function(msg){
             if(msg){
                $('#display').html(msg).show();
             }else{
                $('#display').text("nothing came back");
             }
        }
```

As stated above the ajax submit and display work perfectly except for the format.  I have tried < code >, < pre >.  If I switch the html in success to text I get an unformated jumble of text.  Any ideas?  This is on localhost so I cant show you the page

Formtorch http://formtorch.geekhut.org/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace all the < and > characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: Aw damm guys, I wish I could select both of you.  Thank you very much

Comment: Unfortunately that pooches the php displaying the variables ($v1).  It does display correctly though

Comment: Ignore the above comment, I got it working. Forgot to echo the variable :)

Answer (score 1):

Everything between `<` and `>` is interpreted as a HTML tag, you need to escape it to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively, for example using `$().text();`.